# Python 2.7 Intro. to Classes: "'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, class, oop, module

I got a school assignment which is an introduction to object-oriented programming. I'm really close to solving this problem, just having some problem with the syntax I guess. Perhaps some of you pros knows exactly what the problem is?

Got my class here:

```
class CashRegister():
    __taxRate = 0
    __numProductsSold = 0
    __totalRevenue = 0.0
    __taxAmount = 0.0
    __soldProducts = []

    def __init__(self, taxRate):
        self.__taxRate = taxRate

    def getNumProductsSold(self):
        return self.__numProductsSold

    def getTotalRevenue(self):
        return self.__totalRevenue

    def getTaxAmount(self):
        return self.__taxAmount

    def getSoldProducts(self):
        return self.__soldProducts

    def addItem(self, product, price):
        self.__numProductsSold +=1
        self.__totalRevenue += price
        self.__taxAmount += price * self.__taxRate
        self.__soldProducts.append(product)
```

and I'm trying to call it here:

```
import CashRegister

def main():
    testRegister = CashRegister(22)
    testProduct = "Mat"
    testRegister.addItem(testProduct, 23.99)
    print testRegister.getTotalRevenue ()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

Anyone spotting the problem?
Getting error message as header says.

Comment: Yes. Lost it when copy+pasted.

Comment: Conventional Python style recommends that module names be lowercase (i.e. `cashregister`), which, incidentally, might have made the issue more clear. (`cashregister` the module != `CashRegister` the class)

Comment: What line does the error message say the problem is on?

Answer (score 6):

Python makes no assumptions about the names of your classes from the names of your modules and it allows a module to hold multiple classes. You need to import your classes explicitly or reference them as members of the module object. By convention, module names are lower case and class names begin with an upper case letter. For example:

```
# mymodule.py

class ClassOne(object):
    pass

class ClassTwo(object):
    pass
```

in another file:

```
from mymodule import ClassOne, ClassTwo
one = ClassOne()
```

or

```
import mymodule
one = mymodule.ClassOne()
```

Answer (score 1):

The "CashRegister" class in the imported "CashRegister" module is accessed as `CashRegister.CashRegister`.

Comment: or similarly `from CashRegister import CashRegister`

Comment: I'm so sorry but I really don't understand. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your program which methods from `CashRegister` you want to use, so you have a few options:

> option 1

```
import CashRegister

def main():
    testRegister = CashRegister.CashRegister(22)
    testProduct = "Mat"
    testRegister.addItem(testProduct, 23.99)
    print testRegister.getTotalRevenue ()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

In option 1, you're telling the interpreter to not get confused about which `CashRegister` method you're wanting to call -- it's the one within the `CashRegister` class.

> option 2

```
from CashRegister import CashRegister

def main():
    testRegister = CashRegister(22)
    testProduct = "Mat"
    testRegister.addItem(testProduct, 23.99)
    print testRegister.getTotalRevenue ()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

In option 2, you're telling the interpreter that you're only importing `CashRegister`'s constructor from the class, and this should be assumed when you call `CashRegister` in the code.

There's another option which is not necessary in *this* application, but would still work. It's better when you have many methods within a class. Here's that option.

> option 3

```
from CashRegister import *

def main():
    testRegister = CashRegister(22)
    testProduct = "Mat"
    testRegister.addItem(testProduct, 23.99)
    print testRegister.getTotalRevenue ()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

In option 3, you're telling the compiler that you want to bring *all* of the methods from the class into the scope of the program and you won't need to specify the owning class.